# Django - using sqlalchemy with a read-only database

Tags: django, sqlalchemy, django-middleware

I'm using Django to nicely display stats etc from an Oracle database that I only have/want read access to. Because the database has composite primary keys I'm not using Django's ORM layer and I'm using SQLAlchemy instead. The only installed apps I have are my own, and of the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` I'm only using `CommonMiddleware`.

Based on [this](http://lethain.com/entry/2008/jul/23/replacing-django-s-orm-with-sqlalchemy/) I have a single app accessing the database and working well. I put my sqlalchemy engine, session and orm.mapper all in `models.py` then in my `views.py` I just import the session and the classes that have been mapped.

However now I want to make a second app and obviously I should move the stuff in `models.py` somewhere more generic so that it applies to the whole project, not just one app.

Where should I put it? Should I write some kind of very simple session middleware? Or is there some file that is only executed once when the server starts? Since I never write to the database, should I try and make all requests belong to the same session?

Should I just make random file in the project base like `connect.py` and import it into the settings file?

Currently I am using the built-in server but I will be looking to use probably apache + mod_wsgi at some point.